# MediaScannerConnection fails on Android 6 because of permission denial

Tags: android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I use a MediaScannerConnection to call its scanFile method, for adding images to device gallery. But in Android 6 I receive this exceptions when I execute it:

> E/DatabaseUtils: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:
>   reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/fs_id from pid=22984, uid=10078 requires
>   android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

and

> E/iu.UploadsManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:
>   reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/fs_id from pid=22984, uid=10078 requires
>   android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

Any help?